Electron Kiosk Mode: Not preventing F11, Alt+Tab
I want to build a Kiosk style Application for our factories to replace the old Winforms version. We decided to use Electron + Angular for this, but I cant get the Kiosk mode to work as a Kiosk mode should:
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
let win;
app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow()
})
function createWindow() {
    win = new BrowserWindow({ kiosk: true, });
    win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/dist/index.html`)

    //win.webContents.openDevTools();
    console.log(win.kiosk)
    win.on('closed', function () {
        win = null
    })
}


With this, I can start the app, and the kiosk: true does start the app in fullscreen, but it does not prevent F11, Alt+Tab, Alt+F4 and so on, which - for me - are the key feature of a Kiosk Software.
Any ideas why and how to fix this?
